# Is there a setter method for the "pooling" attribute of the pre-trained models of Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

As the title is self-descriptive, I need to set the `pooling` attribute of a pre-trained model (e.g., `InceptionV3`) object of `Keras` after the object was constructed as I dynamically create the pre-trained model. Is there such a `setter` method in the `Keras` API? As far as I see through debugging, the pooling type is not stored as an attribute in the constructed object, which is a `keras.src.engine.functional.Functional` instance. So, the built-in method `__setattr__` does not help in my case.